# How can I get the attribute value with a condition using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML code as follows.

```
 <div class="main">
    <div class="selected" option="1">options</div>
    <div option="2">options</div>
    <div class="selected" option="3">options</div>
    <div option="4">options</div>
    <div class="selected" option="5">options</div>
    <div option="6">options</div>
</div>
```

How can I get the attribute values [Value of "option"] if the div has class "selected" using jquery?

Comment: when you want to get attribute? on div click event?

Comment: Yes, on "main" class click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use,

```
var arr = $(".main .selected").map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("option")
}).get();
```

This will return an array and assign the result to arr.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5226/)

Answer (score 0):

Although jQuery makes this very easy, you can achieve this with vanilla JS:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++ ) {
    if(els[i].hasAttribute("option")) { // Checks the current element in the loop to see if it has an "option" attribute
        console.log(els[i].getAttribute("option"));
    }
}
```

Here's a working fiddle, it outputs the values to the console for now and returns `1`, `3` and `5` as you'd expect: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lz6w45x/